# unable to get search function work by rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I want to do a simple search for user index by name

model  user.rb

```
    def self.search(query)
       where("username LIKE ?", "%#{query}%")
    end
```

view      for users  I just have *index.html.erb*

```
    <%= form_tag users_search_path, :method => 'get' do %>

    <td><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %></td>

    <%= submit_tag "Search", :class => "buttons buttons-rounded buttons-flat-action", :id => "button-new"%>

  <br><br><br>
  <% end %>
```

controller

```
  @page =  params[:page]
  @search = params[:search];

  def index
   if params[:search]
  @users = User.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @page)
  else
  @users = User.order(:username).joins(:biography).where("`is_active?` = true AND `last_sign_in_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) ").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @page)
    end 
  end

  def search

   Rails.logger.debug("event1: #{@search}")

   redirect_to users_path
   index

   Rails.logger.debug("search start")
  end
```

When I hit the search button, the debugger information is

```
     D, [2014-07-09T13:10:50.755373 #5501] DEBUG -- : event1: 
     D, [2014-07-09T13:10:50.755508 #5501] DEBUG -- : event1:
```

Comment: What do you mean not working? what do get when you call this method?

Comment: You're going to have to specify what "not working" means. Do you get a specific error? If so, **post the stack trace**.

Answer (score 0):

Your search method is wrong, it is redirecting to the index action without the search parameters. You could just submit the form to the index action like this

```
<%= form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

Or be more elegant perhaps like this

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController    
  before_action :filter_data, only: [:index, :search]

  def index

  end

  def search
    render :index
  end

  def filter_data
    if params[:search]
      @users = User.search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: params[:page])
    else
      @users = User.order(:username).joins(:biography).where("`is_active?` = true AND `last_sign_in_at` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) ").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: params[:page])
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.